# How to use a typeclass like `HasDynFlags m` in GHC

Tags: haskell, ghc, typeclass

While playing with GHC code base, I find a typeclass named [`HasDynFlags`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.10.1/docs/html/libraries/ghc-7.10.1/DynFlags.html#t:HasDynFlags):

```
class HasDynFlags m where
    getDynFlags :: m DynFlags
```

Although the typeclass name looks self-explanatory, I couldn't find other
constraints in the typeclass definition that says `m` has to be `Monad` or at least `Functor` so we can get access to that value.

However, most use of it I find in the code base is inside a do-notation, e.g `dynFlag <- getDynFlags` where `m` is further constrainted to be an instance of `Monad`.

My questions are:

- For `HasDynFlags m`, does `m` have to be at least `Functor` to make this typeclass useful?
- If the answer to the first question is no, then how are we supposed to get access to a value of `DynFlags` given `getDynFlags :: m DynFlags`, without any further knowledge about `m`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the class definition,

```
class HasDynFlags m where
    getDynFlags :: m DynFlags
```

`m` is satisfied by kind `(* -> *)`. The kind `(* -> *)` is implied by the type `m DynFlags`, which demonstrates that `m` is a type constructor taking exactly one type parameter.

There are no further constraints on `m` here. Specifically, the resulting type needn't be a Functor (or Monad), although given common naming conventions for type variables in Haskell, there's a good chance Monad is the motivating case.

EDIT: To answer the second question, the Functor or Monad class constraints we expect are introduced in more specific contexts. For example, consider the type,

```
(HasDynFlags m, Monad m) => m DynFlags
```

I think that's all there is to it.